Is "that" optional in "to the extent that"?
Taking a similar example:

Please check that the light is off.
Please check the light is off.

are both correct (the reason given is "the light is off" is a complete sentence).
Now what about:

It'll shrink to the extent that it'll break

Can it be abbreviated in:

It'll shrink to the extent it'll break

I see official publications omitting "that", e.g. from the EU Commission:

Finally Article 87(3)c of the Treaty is relevant to the extent it concerns promotion of training.

Still I suspect it's not correct, but I don't get the exact reason. On the other hand using "that" seems to me a little formal, and I wonder if there are correct alternatives.
I'm asking in general, but my context is mostly American English.

The that actually does not seem necessary to me in your second sentence.  This might be a regional or dialect difference, though.

@stangdon - speaking as a Brit, I'd find 'to the extent it'll break', with 'that' omitted, informal and not only American-sounding, but New Yawkish.

@MichaelHarvey - Reading Ngrams is like reading tea leaves, but I think I do see hints that while the that-ful version is more common on both sides of the pond, it's more more common in Britain: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28to+the+extent+that+it%3Aeng_us%2Fto+the+extent+it%3Aeng_us%29%2C%28to+the+extent+that+it%3Aeng_gb%2Fto+the+extent+it%3Aeng_gb%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en-GB&smoothing=3

@stangdon - yes, given that Ngrams results are derived from indexing printed material, and that any pondial differences are liable to be skewed by each side's publication of the other side's works, any comparative figures for informal spoken English usages are going to be very tea-leafish indeed.

If you're going to say "it'll" you might as well drop  "to the extent that" and say instead "It will shrink so much (that) it breaks".

It is necessary in your second example. "To the extent it will break" could be understood as "how much it will break".
'That' makes it clear you are introducing a subordinate clause and that you are making a link between the extent to which it is shrunk and the possibility of it breaking as a result of that shrinking.
